# Ubuntu 20.04 suddenly can't boot, boots into black screen with blinking underscore cursor

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for a while now. It's been great, but suddenly, today, it can't boot. Whenever I turn on my laptop, it boots into GRUB, I select "Ubuntu", it shows the boot screen, and then ultimately boots into a black screen with a single blinking underscore cursor in the top left.

All the `tty`s work fine. I can access tty2-tty6 just fine and log in. However, I just cannot get into the graphical login screen.

I've tried `nomodeset`, but no luck. I've tried running Boot Repair three times, but it still cannot fix it.

Here's the pastebin log of my latest run of Boot Repair: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/DMr56dqFsY/

Ubuntu was working fine yesterday, and has been working fine ever since I updated - but it suddenly does this now. I searched on the internet quite a bit and it seems most people only get this problem right after an update. I could not find any discussions or posts about it suddenly happening when it was working fine the day before.

Does anyone know what's going on and how I can fix it?

Comment: I see lots of posts like this.  Happened even once on my VBox install.  If you can get to the TTY then you are doing well.  I don't think it is a Boot Repair issue though good job trying. From the TTY make sure you update all to make sure you have the latest packages.  Try also to ls into your home folder to make sure it is present. Then if not working go back to Grub.  From the grub screen arrow down and boot an older kernel. You should have a total of three to pick from. Then report back.

Comment: Do you have the NVIDIA proprietary driver installed?

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me most of the time.

Ctrl+Alt+F2

This should bring the command line log in. I don't bother logging in I go ahead and press

Ctrl+Alt+F1

This then shows the window manager.

Mind you this will not fix a messed up grub.